# DocuSign resend: This user lacks sufficient permissions to access this resource

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I'm attempting to resend an envelope to recipients but get "This user lacks sufficient permissions to access this resource." The envelope was sent by our api user on behalf of another user which is also in the account. So the initial envelope creation would have looked like:

```
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <n:DocuSignCredentials xmlns:n="http://www.docusign.com/restapi"><IntegratorKey>MY-KEY</IntegratorKey><Password>password</Password><Username>api-user@here.there</Username><SendOnBehalfOf>other.user@somwhere.else</SendOnBehalfOf></n:DocuSignCredentials>
...
```

That succeeded and I can pull up the envelope audit events via the rest api. However, attempting to resend the envelope using the existing recipients as is as the same api-user results in:

```
<errorDetails>
  <errorCode>USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS</errorCode>
  <message>This user lacks sufficient permissions to access this resource.</message>
</errorDetails>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my error was in not specifying the same SendOnBehalfOf user when attempting the resend. Adding that in allows things to work as expected. Same for voiding an envelope and presumably any other envelope altering operation.

Comment: Yep.  Since you used "SendOnBehalfOf" in the Create Envelope API request, that user is considered the sender (owner) of the Envelope and as such, will be the only user who can take additional (sender) actions on that Envelope in the future (ex: Correct, Void, etc.).  Specifying only the "API User" in the X-DocuSign-Authentication header of a subsequent API request for an Envelope that's "owned by" (sent by) another user will always result in the "USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS" error.